# DMARC - Specific conditions for message to pass DMARC authentication

Tags: email

DMARC is used to further secure domains against email phishing. It relies on two distinct other standards - SPF and DKIM.

When an email arrives, it is checked whether it passes SPF and DKIM. However, point 5 in [section 6.6.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7489#section-6.6.2) of the DKIM RFC states:

```
Conduct Identifier Alignment checks.  With authentication checks
and policy discovery performed, the Mail Receiver checks to see
if Authenticated Identifiers fall into alignment as described in
Section 3.  If one or more of the Authenticated Identifiers align
with the RFC5322.From domain, the message is considered to pass
the DMARC mechanism check.  All other conditions (authentication
failures, identifier mismatches) are considered to be DMARC
mechanism check failures.
```

The wording is a little confusing for me, specifically the `If one or more of the Authenticated Identifiers align with the RFC5322.From domain` -- Does that mean that, per the RFC, a message that has only 1 RFC5322.From aligned "Authenticated Identifier", is valid and passes the DMARC?

Example:
If a message has an aligned SPF, but fails DKIM verification (Or lacks DKIM signature completely, not sure if that makes a difference), it still passes DMARC? Wouldn't that be pretty insecure for domains that, for example, use Gmail to send emails, and thus have included Google's SPF in their SPF record?

All an attacker then would have to do is send out the phishing email from Gmail with a forged FROM header and MAIL FROM, and it'd be both, SPF valid and aligned, thus passing DMARC, despite completely missing the usually present DKIM.

Note: Not sure if the example is all that valid with Gmail as it relies on raw SMTP-level raw access. But despite that, I could use the clarification on DMARC validation flow.